# Distinct-style filtering on a Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Distinct might be the wrong word for what I want but I have a `Message` class like the following for a simple flat messaging system between users:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messagefromuser')
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messagetouser')
    when = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.TextField()
```

This allows two users to chat about a single Thread object. The system is designed to allow two users to have separate conversations on separate Threads.

So as it is, I can grab the messages a given user is involved in with the following query:

```
Message.objects.filter( Q(from_user=u) | Q(to_user=u) )
```

That outputs every message a user has sent or received. I'm building a page where users can see all their conversations with other users, grouped by thread. This is the *ideal* output that I can imagine getting to:

```
[
    {
        'thread': thread_instance,
        'conversations': [
            {
                'other_user': user_instance
                'latest_reply': date_time_instance
            },
            ....
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I have thought about iterating this from the top, but unless there's a way to filter through `Thread` into `Message`'s `to_user`, `from_user` fields, there are just too many threads. The DB server would melt.

- "Group" the messages by `Thread`
- "Group" those by the other user so each group is between two distinct users, per `Thread`
- Pluck the most recent `to_user=u` and annotate something with that.

I'm going a little crazy trying to warp my brain around the particulars. In my head it feels like something you should be able to do in a couple of lines but I just can't see how.

Comment: why isn't the to_user and from_user properties of the Thread? I may be missing something about the use-case, but it seems to be easier to get the view you descirbed. Then you get the messages of a thread only when you need.

Comment: @OmerGertel (Confusingly) the `Thread` class isn't actually about messaging at all. It's an object that one of the two users in a conversation will have generated at some point. Once generated another user can start a conversation with the owner of the thread and then the owner can reply. If the system were StackOverflow, `Thread` would be the question and Message would be a kind of private comment system discussing a question.

Comment: But now you've said that, I see a possibility: I could add another layer between `Thread` and `Message` called `MessageThread` to create a utility buffer between the two (just like a real messaging thread would). The system is very young so I can still afford to rinse the data if it makes things easier.

Comment: the `MessageThread` is probably a good idea

Answer (score 0):

```
threads = Thread.objects.filter(
  Q(message_set__from_user=u) | Q(message_set__to_user=u)
).order_by('id')

messages = Message.objects.filter(
  Q(thread__in=threads) & Q(Q(thread__from_user=u) | Q(thread_to_user=u))
).order_by('thread__id', '-when').select_related('from_user', 'to_user')

from itertools import groupby

t_index = 0
for thread_messages in groupby(messages, lambda x: x.thread_id):
  if threads[t_index].id is thread_messages[0].thread_id:
    threads[t_index].messages = thread_messages

  t_index += 1
```

That might look a bit complex or scary but it *should* do what you are after. Essentially it queries all your threads first so we can find out what threads we've messaged about. Then it finds all the related messages to those threads.

Both of the queries are ordered by the same field so that in the lower part of the code we can iterate through the list only once, instead of needing a nested for loop to find each thread with the correct id. They are also both filtered by the same query (regarding thread objects at least) to ensure we are getting back only the relevant results to this query.

Lastly, the messages that we received back are grouped together and attached to each thread; they will show up in descending order for each thread.

Right at the end, you may also want to re-sort your threads to show the latest ones first, easy to do assuming a 'when' field on the Thread model:

threads = sorted(threads, key=lambda x: x.when, reverse=True)

By using the aforementioned method, you will have to do 2 queries every time, regardless, first the threads, then the messages. But it will never go above this (watch out for joins on a select_related though or recursive queries on related objects).